# How to change the counter of a for-loop in python?

Tags: python, mysql, for-loop

Is it possible to change the counter of a loop inside an exception?

I have tried some different syntax. It does work inside the exception, but when the loop executes again, the change doesn't seem to be applied.

```
for b in range(6, len(attribute_column)):
    try:
        print(b)
        print(attribute_column[b])
        qu = """ALTER TABLE products ADD %s NVARCHAR(200)""" % (attribute_column[b])
        mycursor.execute(qu)
    #if there is a multivalued column in json, POP the value and save it for another insertion
    except mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError:
        print(b)
        attribute_column.pop(b)
        redundant_values[attribute_column[b]] = attribute_value.pop(b)
        b = b-1
        print(b)
```

The output is this:

```
6
7
8
9
9
8
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

I need it to be this:

```
6
7
8
9
9
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

Comment: make use and while loops and if conditions which don't increment or decrement your indexes according to your conditions

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Is this an XY problem?

Comment: You could use a while loop perhaps? however, tackling into why you'd want to do this, there's probably a better way to do whatever you're trying to do by using conditionals and skipping redundant values. iterating over indexes in python is usually not necessary, and considered an antipattern for good reason.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh I'm trying to alter my table according to a long list of new columns which may have some repetitive columns .what I'm trying to do here is skipping those columns and save the corresponding value in attrbute_value. The problem is just with the loop, not with what I'm trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Not judging your whole approach but in general, if you need arbitrary state changes in a counter, you can write your custom iterator:

```
class Cursor:

    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.end = end
        self.position = start

    def __next__(self):
        if self.position >= self.end:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self.position += 1
            return  self.position - 1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def revert(self, n=1):
        self.position -= n + 1
```

Example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    cursor = Cursor(6, 16)
    it = iter(range(3, -20, -1)) # for demo

    for i in cursor:
        print(i)
        try:
            i / next(it)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print("Error on:", i)
            cursor.revert(1)
```

Output:

```
6
7
8
9
Error on: 9
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15

Process finished with exit code 0
```